# How to scratch an itchy throat

Tags: home-remedies, otolaryngology, itching, throat, scratch-scratching

My throat is seriously itching me and it seems totally impossible to scratch it. Is there any home-remedy i can use to scratch it, I'm just hoping that it isn't some kind of disease or anything related.

Comment: You could try gargling with water.

Comment: Believe me, I've tried

Comment: Anything health-related that has a word **seriously** in its description deserves a trip to the doctor's office.

Comment: Not just water. Gargle with warm salt water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically [itchy throats](http://www.webmd.com/cold-and-flu/features/get-to-the-bottom-of-your-sore-throat#1) are associated with post nasal drip, dry air, allergies, or some other irritant.

If it's allergen related, an antihistamine (Benadryl, Zyrtec, Claritin, etc) can be helpful. If you're developing some sort of virus or bacterial infection, often a warm salt water gargle helps to alleviate discomfort and can prevent a full-on infection.

How long has your throat been itchy? If this is an on-going problem, I'd advise seeing your health care provider.

Also, [hot tea with honey](http://www.healthcentral.com/allergy/c/2048/10075/itchy-throat/) can provide temporary relief as the honey will coat your throat.